# How to send a download request to a server without downloading the file?

Tags: download, denial-of-service

I want to send a request to a server to download a file. However, when the file is sent by the server, I don't want to actually receive the file. I'm trying to see if it's possible for me to overload a server's bandwidth without having to actually download files.

I'm guessing this should be possible using some sort of a UDP protocol where no acknowledgements are required.

Answer (score 0):

If the download is available via HTTP GET, you can try sending an HTTP HEAD request with the same headers to try to receive a response without the server actually sending the file.

Comment: No, I meant let the server send the file. I don't want to consume any bandwidth trying to download it. All I want to do is keep the server busy

Comment: If you're streaming the receive, you can just ignore/drop the received data chunks as you receive them.